# Calling files with c(x:y)

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a large number of files (in GB size).I want to run a for loop in which I call some files, do so processing that creates some files, bind them together, and save it.

```
AA<-c(1,6)
BB<-c(5,10)
for(i in length(AA)){
    listofnames<-list.files(pattern="*eng")
    listofnames<- listofnames[c(paste(AA[i],BB[i],sep=":"))]
    listoffiles <- lapply( listofnames, readRDS)
}
```

But listofnames has NA. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: @JohnColeman No, my first line is setwd(...), which I did not show in my sample code.

Comment: At what point does NA arise?

Comment: I have some advice, but can you fix the typos in your example code first?

Comment: @JohnColeman Am I mistaking at the 5th line?

Comment: @joran Is it fine now?

Comment: It couldn't hurt to print it between the two lines to determine where the problem first occurs.

Comment: Also `i in 1:length(AA)` maybe?

Comment: I think it is now. And yes, the right hand side of line 5 is wrong. Indexing by name only works for a named vector, which `list.files` does not return. You'll need to index by position, or use `grep` or something.

Comment: It's hard to say if the `paste()` statement is even right, because we have no idea what your file names actually are, so that could be wrong, but we'd have no way to know.

Comment: When I do listofnames<- listofnames[c(1:5))] it works fine.

Comment: Yes, exactly my point.

Comment: @joran will you kindly suggest an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while looking at your code to realize that you were actually trying to construct a *character* representation of the expression `1:5` that was supposed to index a vector by position. This is very wrong; you just can't `paste` together arbitrary R commands/expressions and expect to drop them in to you code wherever. (Technically, there are tools that do that sort of thing, but they are discouraged.)

Probably you're looking to do something closer to:

```
listofnames <- list.files(pattern="*eng")
ind <- rep(1:5,each = 5,length.out = length(listofnames))
listofnames_split <- split(listofnames,ind)

for (i in seq_along(listofnames_split)){
  my_data <- lapply(listofnames_split[[i]], readRDS)
  #Do processing here
  #...
  rm(my_data) #Assuming memory really is a problem
}
```

But I'm just sketching out hypothetical code here, I can't really match it to your exact situation since your example isn't really fully fleshed out.

Comment: Would you elaborate first three lines?

Comment: @runjumpfly (1) List all the file, (2) Create a vector of indexes in groups of 5, (3) Split vector of file names into sets of 5.

Comment: Thanks @joran the result of the for loop is what I need. I will accept it. But I am not able to understand how rep() works in this context. and so I am not able to select 2 files groups instead of 20 files * 5 groups.